# 301 redirect inside php if statement

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to redirect pages that don't match a certain id, but when I add the following code, the page redirects no matter what, even if the catid is 27.

```
if($contenti[0]['catid'] != '27'){
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    Header( "Location: http://website.nl" );    
}else{
    echo 'test';    
}
```

When I echo catid it shows 27, so it should not redirect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to see what `$contenti[0]['catid']` outputs? maybe it has white space ? Take into account that: `!=` only matches the value and not the data type, whilst `!==` matches the value and data type.

Comment: It shows `27` and there is no whitespace since it comes from a barebone joomla database.

Comment: Do a var_dump of `$contenti` to see the type and values of the array, additionally `header's H has to be in lower case`

Comment: ok.. I added some extra notes to my initial comment.

Comment: I found my problem, the headers were already sent, but now I get an infinite redirect loop, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Add `exit;` after `header()`. To avoid infinite loop you shouldn't redirect users to the same page, create another address like 404 error page.

Comment: I need to redirect to the homepage because of SEO reasons. So I i made an if statement if catid is '' (empty, because the homepage does not have a catid) to do nothing, but still I get an infinity redirect loop. Even with exit after the headers.